# Синтаксис jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript, синтаксис

Как сделать чтобы код заработал?

```
$(".saveAll").attr("action", .append("" + i + ""));
```

в элементе с классом saveAll, в атрибут action, в конец добавляем значение переменной.
Этот код в цикле, так что нужно что бы именно добавляло в конец атрибута.

Спасибо

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.append(..)` — вызов метода `append` "из ниоткуда".

Метод `append` вызывается из обьекта, например `$(`*`selector`*`).append(...)`. Важно подметить, что данный метод работает из внутренним содержимым блока, тоесть добавляет текст к `innerHTML`, а не к какому-либо из атрибутов.

Так как вам нужно работать не со внутренним содержимым, а именно с атрибутом `action`, нужно узнавать его текущее значение и уже к нему добавлять нужную строчку. Исходя из того, что обьект не один, при добавлении атрибута нужно работать именно з текущим обьектом, тоесть выбирать обьекты по селектору `$('.saveAll')` не можно, нужно работать с обьектом `$(this)`. Именно из-за этого, нужно еще использовать метод `.each()`.

```
$('.saveAll').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('action',$(this).attr('action')+i);
})
```

Comment: благодарю за столь содержательный ответ. все работает. буду знать на будущее